# How to join two electrical boxes through a wall?

Tags: subpanel, conduit

I'm replacing a 1960s vintage sub-panel for my laundry and air-conditioner. I'm also looking to install a disconnect at the A/C compressor. The new sub-panel is inside the wall of the laundry room, and the disconnect is being mounted opposite it on the outside wall with knockouts aligned (3/4"). I'd like to run a raceway from the one box to the other, but it's too far for a box spacer...at least the ones in stock at Lowe's. I measure 2-3/4" from the inside of the one box to the inside of the other. What's the best means of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of Rigid conduit and four conduit nuts.

And some plastic conduit bushings won't hurt to avoid the wire being cut on the pipe edge that you are supposed to de-burr (and should come that way if pre-made).

The inner conduit nuts are installed with the bitey side outward. Then the boxes are installed over them. Then another conduit nut is run down over them, crimping the box for a good electrical connection.

If you have the space for connectors, you can do the same with an EMT conduit nipple.

Comment: Some plastic conduit bushings are a great idea, especially with the rigid nipple.